# How to exclude files from lgtm code analysis?

Tags: python, static-code-analysis

Writing python code and using [LGTM](https://lgtm.com) for automated code analysis.  How can LGTM be advised to ignore (or exclude form its analysis) entire files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put a configuration file `lgtm.yml` at the root of your repository and specify the files to exclude there:

https://lgtm.com/help/lgtm/customizing-file-classification

Comment: this only exclude the test file?